# How do I responsively center columns with bootstrap vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on a project in which I need to vertically need to center one column, nested in another one. I have tried to do it myself using the `display: table !important` property and `vertical-align: central`, but I didn't succeed.

Here's what I should look like:

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/J8xL8/3/)

Thank you so much for you help,

I greatly appreciate!

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise `central` was OK to use... (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#vertical-align) but try `middle;`

Comment: Hi Alex, doesn't really seem to work, I tried `vertical-align: middle OR central`, none of them work.

Comment: Hmm weird. I'll look into it.

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML that I can work with, that is similar to your code?

Comment: beat alex, this is very similar to my code. Just look into my JSFiddle. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes:

```
<div class="col-xs-8" >
   <div class="content">
     <h3>Heading Example</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- stylesheet --

```
.content{
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
}
```